# How to securely delete files from Sharepoint (so they are unrecoverable)

Tags: file, delete

My business is looking for a way to delete files from their sharepoint pages permanently making them untraceable and unrecoverable.

When we delete them now they go into a recycle bin, we can then delete them from there however they go into a secondary recycle bin and are kept in there for a period of time before sharepoint deletes them. From here I believe they are still on the drive just waiting to be over written.

What is the best way to ensure these files cannot be recovered.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can delete them from the secondary recycle bin which will remove their entry completely from the content database.

Comment: Could they still be recovered forensically from the hard drive?

Comment: SharePoint content resides in a database (usually) and not on disk like a file system. Once they're deleted from the database they're not recoverable except from backups of the database.

Comment: Can the files be easily removed from the backups of the db so there is no trace?